# UIKeyInput keyboard type protocol requirement does not match

Tags: swift, uikit, protocols, uikeyboardtype, uikeyinput

I have a `UIView` subclass which conforms to `UIKeyInput` protocol. I want to set the keyboard type to `numberPad`. Unfortunately, setting this property does nothing.

```
var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType {
    .numberPad
}
```

Compiler warns me with the following description:

`Property 'keyboardType' nearly matches optional requirement 'keyboardType' of protocol 'UITextInputTraits'`

Therefore, I know that this property does not refer to the `UIKeyInput` protocol. 
I was looking for other protocols or classes called `UIKeyInput`, but I didn't find any.

Do you have any suggestion what else can cause this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/1624457-keyboardtype) show you should provide getter and setter for this property.

```
optional var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType { get set }
```